# Error when deploying Geolocation field - no such column

Tags: deployment, geolocation, compound-fields

I have an Apex class that allows me to calculate distances between two records using a geolocation field as these are required when using the `DISTANCE` function. Everything is great until I am trying to deploy it to production. The compound field itself is called `location__c`. I created it in production as well. However when I deploy Salesforce tells me there is "no such column location__c on entity account".

There is no spelling mistake. I also checked permission - everything checks out. Even when I deploy the field together with my Apex class I get the error. I have a feeling it's a geolocation field problem. Has anyone else run into that problem and has a solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you check the data type of the "location__c" field in the production environment? It's possible that another field with the same name exists but is of a different data type. Also, is GeoLocation enabled in Prod?

Comment: Hello @VijayaKapadam thanks for reaching out. Yes, both are of the type "Geolocation" and both go by "location__c". As a matter if fact "Maps and Location" (Enable Maps) was not enabled on production! Unfortunetaly the deployment throws the same error still

Data integration rules for account are enabled

Comment: Please re-verify the field-level security settings again for the "location__c" field in the Account object. Ensure that the field is accessible by the user's profile performing the deployment. Also, ensure at least the profile can read the field in 'field accessibility'.
I would try to deploy this field alone with the above changes and deploy the apex class later.